# Opening Files and Performing File Input in Python

Tags: python

I am having trouble making python read and print the names of flowers. I have to create a while loop to read the input until EOF is reached. The codes that I made is in a continuous loop.

```
myFlowers = open("flowers.dat" , "r")
var = myFlowers.readline()
var2 = myFlowers.readline()

while var != "EOF" and var2 != "":
    print(var + "grow in the" + var2)

var = myFlowers.readline()
var2 = myFlowers.readline()
myFlowers.close()
```

```
flower.dot:
1.Astilbe
2.Shade
3.Marigold
4.Sun
5.Begonia
6.Sun
7.Primrose
8.Shade
9.Cosmos
10.Sun
11.Dahlia
12.Sun
13.Geranium 
14.Sun
15.Foxglove
16.Shade
17.Trillium
18.Shade
19.Pansy
20.Sun
21.Petunia
22.Sun
23.Daisy
24.Sun
25.Aster
26.Sun
```

Code has to read:

```
Astilbe grows in the Shade, 
Marigold grows in the Sun, 
Begonia grows in the Sun, 
Primrose grows in the Shade, 
Cosmos grows in the Sun, 
Dahlia grows in the Sun, 
Geranium grows in the Sun, 
Foxglove grows in the Shade, 
Trillium grows in the Shade, 
Pansy grows in the Sun,
Petunia grows in the Sun, 
Daisy grows in the Sun, 
Aster grows in the Sun,
```

Comment: Use a context manager to handle files! Just use a for loop to iterate over the lines. Can you format the input data as it appears in the file? (I submitted an edit)

Comment: Is your code indented the same way in your program? Your loop never reads the lines.

Comment: Why do you have to use a while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this as follows:

```
with open('flower.dot') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)-1,2):
        flower = lines[i].split('.')[-1].replace('\n','')
        likes = lines[i+1].split('.')[-1].replace('\n','')
        print('{} grows in the {},'.format(flower,likes))
```

The for loop goes thru your file two-by-two (the third argument in the for loop is an increment). The `lines[i].split('.')[-1]`  gives you the remainder of the line after the last '.', and the `.replace('\n','') removes the newlines that occur at the end of every line in your original file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong indentation, this piece:

```
while var != "EOF" and var2 != "":
    print(var + "grow in the" + var2)

var = myFlowers.readline()
var2 = myFlowers.readline()
myFlowers.close()
```

should look like this:

```
while var != "EOF" and var2 != "":
    print(var + "grow in the" + var2)

    var = myFlowers.readline()
    var2 = myFlowers.readline()
myFlowers.close()
```

Otherwise the variables `var` and `var2` will never get the new values from the file.

Comment: It works thanks, but now the issue is that the “var” get printed on top of each other and not next to each other. I think I have a space issue that I haven’t found.

Comment: @Yan you have to `var = var.strip()` to get rid of the spaces (and CR / LF characters) on the end of the lines. Or just do `var = MyFlowers.readline().strip()`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a while loop, you could monitor the file's *position* and use it to know when to stop. The following example shows what happens to the position when reading lines"

```
In [63]: with open('foo.csv') as f:
    ...:     print(f.tell())
    ...:     x = f.readlines()
    ...:     print(f.tell())
    ...:     z = f.readline()
    ...:     print(f.tell())
    ...:     
0
606
606

In [64]:
```

When the end of the file is reached. `readline()` won't cause the file's position to change. That can be used to stop the loop:

```
In [67]: f = open('foo.csv')

In [68]: last_postion, new_position = 0,1

In [69]: while last_postion != new_position:
    ...:     last_postion = new_position
    ...:     x = f.readline()
    ...:     new_position = f.tell()
    ...:     print(last_postion,new_position, end=',')
    ...:     
1 2,2 7,7 12,12 17,17 22,22 27,27 32,32 37,37 42,42 47,47 52,52 58,58 64,64 70,70 76,76 82,82 88,88 94,94 100,100 106,106 112,112 118,118 124,124 130,130 136,136 142,142 148,148 154,154 160,160 166,166 172,172 178,178 184,184 190,190 196,196 202,202 208,208 214,214 220,220 226,226 232,232 238,238 244,244 250,250 256,256 262,262 268,268 274,274 280,280 286,286 292,292 298,298 304,304 309,309 314,314 319,319 324,324 329,329 334,334 339,339 344,344 349,349 354,354 360,360 366,366 372,372 378,378 384,384 390,390 396,396 402,402 408,408 414,414 420,420 426,426 432,432 438,438 444,444 450,450 456,456 462,462 468,468 474,474 480,480 486,486 492,492 498,498 504,504 510,510 516,516 522,522 528,528 534,534 540,540 546,546 552,552 558,558 564,564 570,570 576,576 582,582 588,588 594,594 600,600 606,606 606,

In [70]: f.close()
```